# How to replace existing object in array only modifying its props and not affect to other items?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-apollo, react-state-management, react-class-based-component

I'm trying to add item to the cart. If it is in cart, I want to replace this item with updated count and total accordingly, but I don't want to affect to other items. If it is not in cart I add it (logic of if statement). How to implement logic of else statement?

```
class ProductProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cart: [],
      modalOpen: false,
      modalProduct: {},
      cartTotal: 0,
    };
  }

  addToCart = (product) => {
    const index = this.state.cart.findIndex((item) => item.id === product.id);
    if (index === -1) {
      const tempProduct = { ...product };
      tempProduct.inCart = true;
      tempProduct.count = 1;
      const price = product.prices[0].amount;
      tempProduct.total = price;

      this.setState(
        () => {
          return { cart: [...this.state.cart, tempProduct] };
        },
        () => {
          this.addTotal();
        }
      );
    } else {
            // solution must be here
    }
  };

    addTotal = () => {
    let total = 0;
    this.state.cart.map((item) => (total += item.total));

    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        cartTotal: parseFloat(total.toFixed(2)),
      };
    });
  };
}
```

Seems like this approach, I'm currently trying to apply in other component works well. I need to test it and adapt for previous case.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      readMore: false,
      activeID: null,
      activeAtt: null,
      selectedAttributes: [],
    };
  }

  setAttributes = (name, value) => {
    const index = this.state.selectedAttributes.findIndex(
      (item) => item.name === name
    );
    if (index === -1) {
      const newAttribute = { name, value };

      this.setState(() => {
        return {
          selectedAttributes: [...this.state.selectedAttributes, newAttribute],
        };
      });
    } else {
      const tempAttributes = [...this.state.selectedAttributes];
      const selectedAttribute = tempAttributes.find(
        (attribute) => attribute.name === name
      );
      selectedAttribute.value = value;
      this.setState(() => {
        return { selectedAttributes: [...tempAttributes] };
      });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I don't want to affect to other items"?

Comment: I mean I want to modify only existing object in cart array with new values and replace it, but if object is not in cart array yet I want to add it there as a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else {
      const tempCart = [...this.state.cart];
      const selectedItem = tempCart.find((item) => item.id === product.id);
      selectedItem.selectedAttributes = attributes;
      selectedItem.count = selectedItem.count + 1;
      const price = product.prices[0].amount;
      selectedItem.total = selectedItem.total + price;

      this.setState(
        () => {
          return { cart: [...tempCart] };
        },
        () => {
          this.addTotal();
        }
      );
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).